# Why changing directory with `/../` works?

Tags: shell

Change directory:

```
$ pwd
/usr
$ cd bin && pwd
/usr/bin
```

With `..`, same outcome:

```
$ pwd
/usr
$ cd bin/../bin && pwd
/usr/bin
```

But why? Why the shell is not throwing an error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well ".." is a normal entry in the directory (as is ".") as you can see by "ls -la" for example and points to the parent directory.

So splitting your "cd bin/../bin" makes you move from usr to usr/bin, then back to usr, then back to usr/bin. After each "/" the directory move is made.

You can also try cd bin/./././../bin/../bin/./. in case :)

Comment: Shell just splits the path by `/` into tokens and keep changing the directory according each token until all tokens are exhausted or error occurs? Any impact of keeping doing `../../../..`?

Comment: Exactly it just splits and then executes every single token. So doing ../../../.. will move you backwards in the directory tree by 4 levels (of course given the fact that this path exists)

Comment: Actually, it's not "exactly" that.  It isn't the shell doing the path processing (on most operating systems).  It's the operating system kernel.  And whether the root is its own parent directory (which affects whether you can keep adding .. path components willy-nilly) is something that varies from operating system to operating system.